# Use Output directive with array in Angular

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I am trying to using `@Output` directive and emitting `number[]` values.

so:

```
@Output() numberArrayOutput = new EventEmitter<number[]>();
```

And in method, I got dropdown index (it is working) and trying emit:

```
this.numberArrayOutput[this.dropdownIndex].emit(numberValue));
```

And that solution is not working. Still I have error:

> cannot read property 'emit' of undefined

There are any problem to using @Output directive with array of numbers, strings etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `new EventEmitter<number[]>()` you're declaring an `Output` that emits an array of numbers but you're treating it as an array of emitters. If you wanna emit a single number you should have in your component:

```
@Output() numberArrayOutput = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

and then in your method:

```
this.numberArrayOutput.emit(numberValue[this.dropdownIndex]));
```

Assuming that `numberValue` is the array with the data you want to emit. Otherwise if you need to emit an array leave the emitter declaration as you have it and in your method:

```
this.numberArrayOutput.emit(numberArray);
```

This time assuming that `numberArray` is the array you wanna emit.

Comment: I would like to emits array of number in specific index. F.e. I would like emit [,x,] only this position, another time [x, ,] only this position. So - I would like to emit number[]. Not number.